# remove decimal and leading zeros

Tags: vbscript

Below is some vbscript that populates a field called `Lot`. At the moment when I run this the Lot field is displaying the ManualLot field as `123456.000000`.

Does anyone know how I can change the code below to make `123456.000000` just `0000123456`? So it removes the `.000000` and starts with `0000` instead.

```
Function ManualLot_OnAfterChange()
  If Backflushing.CodeObject.Quantity < 0 Then
    Backflushing.CodeObject.Lot = Backflushing.CodeObject.ManualLot
  Else
    If Backflushing.CodeObject.Quantity > 0 Then
      Backflushing.CodeObject.Lot = 0
    End If
  End If
End Function
```

Comment: `"0000" & (123456.000000 * 1)` ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Split()` get the value to the left of the decimal, and then use `Left()` to stick some zeros in front of it.

```
'how long the number should be
testLength=10

'The number we are changing
test="12345.00000"

'split(test, ".")(0) will get us the values to the left of the decimal
test=LEFT("000000000000",  testLength-len(split(test, ".")(0))) & split(test, ".")(0)

msgbox(test)
```

Comment: Hello JNevill. Thanks for your reply. In this case I have Backflushing.CodeObject.Lot = Backflushing.CodeObject.ManualLot and it is the Backflushing.CodeObject.Lot  field that is changing the manually entered number from Backflushing.CodeObject.ManualLot to 123456.000000 so the 123456 is manually typed in by the operator so it will be different everytime. So how would i incorporate your answer into my code?

Comment: @Adam Perhaps surprisingly, you need to replace the variable `test` from the example with the actual variable that holds the data you want to re-format.

Comment: @JNevill You're thinking too complicated. Concatenate first, then use the `Right` function to trim surplus leading zeroes. If `.` is the decimal separator you can use the `Int` function as an alternative to splitting the value. `Right(String(testlength, "0") & Int(test), testlength)`

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, That's great! I like the `int()` idea. I just went straight-string parsing. I guess I just love me some `split()`; probably to my own detriment.

Answer (score -2):

```
Backflushing.CodeObject.Lot = RTrim (Backflushing.CodeObject.ManualLot)
```

Fixed it for me. Thanks for the help though JNevil got me on right track.

Comment: `RTrim` can't possibly do what you were asking in your question.

Comment: see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c623wz83%28v=vs.84%29.aspx to learn that RTrim does *neither* remove trailing .0's nor prepends 0's.